# Probability and Data Integrity

Tags: probability, group-theory, number-theory, probability-distributions, finite-fields

This question is about probability and Security (i.e. data integrity).
The scenario I am going to explain is a client-server case where the server may modify the client's data.

---

We define a field $\mathbb{F}_q$, where $q=2p+1$, $q$  and $p$ are large prime numbers (e.g. |p|= 256-bit).

The client who has value $b \in \mathbb{F}_q$, masks it as $M=(r_1\cdot b+r_2)\bmod q$, where $r_1$ and $r_2$ are picked uniformly random from the field, where $r_1,r_2>\frac{q}{2}$.

- The client sends only  $M$ to the server and it deletes $b$.
- The client can download $M$ and check its data integrity:

  (1) $s_1=(M-  r_2)\bmod q$

  (2) $s_2= (s_1\cdot (r_1)^{-1} )\bmod q=b$

  (3) If $s_2$ was a uniformly random value the client can (magically) detect it.
- We know that if the server finds $k=c\cdot r_1, k<q$ it can modify value $b$ by computing $M+k$. So we would have $s_2=b+c$ and this attack cannot be detected.
- Otherwise ($k\neq c\cdot r_1$), $s_2$ would be uniformly random value because  $s_2=b+(r_1)^{-1}\cdot k\ $  is a uniformly random value.

**Question:** What is the probability that the server modifies $M$ without being detected?

Comment: @MorganRodgers Yes.

Comment: @MorganRodgers I meant any $k, k<q$. consider in a field {1,...23}, if  $r_1=2$, then if the server picks $k=2,4,6,8,12$ it can escape from detection. But if  $r_1=13$, then the whatever the server picks (e.g. h) the result is uniformly random because  $b+(13)^{-1}\cdot h$, as $(13)^{-1}$ is a uniformly random value.

Comment: @MorganRodgers That is why I defined $q=2p+1$ so the $r_i$ can be defined  as $r_i>\frac{q}{2}$

Comment: @MorganRodgers You're right. What would your answer be to the question?

Comment: @MorganRodgers Server picks an "arbitrary" value $k$ then computes $M+k$. The client takes the three above steps. So it gets $v=b+(r_1)^{-1}\cdot k$. Why do you think $v$ is not uniformly random value? Note the server did not change $M$ to a uniformly random value $M'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server modifies $M$, and replaces it with $M^{\prime}$, then 
$(M^{\prime} - r_{2})\cdot (r_{1})^{-1} \neq b$. Ever.

This is because, with $r_{1} \neq 0$, $f(x) = r_{1}\cdot x + r_{2}$ is a one-to-one function, therefore so is its inverse $f^{-1}(x) = (x- r_{2}) \cdot (r_{1})^{-1}$ and so you cannot have $f^{-1}(M^{\prime}) = f^{-1}(M) = b$ unless $M^{\prime} = M$.

Now, given that the server changes $M$ to $M^{\prime}$, the client will download and use $r_{1}$ and $r_{2}$ to "check" and obtain a $b^{\prime} = f^{-1}(M^{\prime})$.  Each choice of $M^{\prime}$ leads to a unique $b^{\prime}$, so if $M^{\prime}$ is chosen uniformly randomly, then $b^{\prime}$ will be chosen uniformly randomly.

Note that there is no real way to say whether a single, fixed field element is "uniformly random" or not.  So I can't say anything particular about the probability that you are asking about. (but as near as I can understand your question, I think it is always "uniformly random").

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But the question is whether the server can modify $M'$ in a way that $b$ becomes non-unifromly (random) element of the field. Because we can detect it only when $b$ is uniformly random value of the field.

Comment: Nobody holds $b$. Value $b$ is embedded in $M$.

Comment: Rodger Can I ask you please where $v=(r)^{-1}\cdot a+b$ is a uniformly random value where $r$ is a uniformly at random value but $ b,a$ are fixed values?

Comment: Well you can ignore $b$ completely, since it is fixed (in other words $r^{-1}\cdot a + b$ is uniformly random if and only if $r^{-1}\cdot a$ is uniformly random).  And then $r^{-1} \cdot a$ is uniformly random (as long as $a \neq 0$) because multiplication by $a$ is a bijection so the $q-1$ possibilities for $r$ give $q-1$ possibilities for $r^{-1}$ and $q-1$ possibilities for $r^{-1} \cdot a$.

Comment: It's the same question.

Comment: @Do you think so? because now I'm not making any assumption on the random values. So they can be picked uniformly at random from the field.

Comment: It's the same.  If you restrict the values for $r$, then (as answered in your other questions), it is uniformly random on a subset of the field.  If you don't restrict $r$ (you implicitly are restricting to $r \neq 0$) then it is uniformly random on... ok, maybe a subset of the field still (missing one element) but essentially nothing is changed.